# My Google Map is showing only to me on my Facebook App

Tags: php, facebook, google-maps, heroku

Hello i uploaded my PHP App on facebook using heroku!

My App is a quiz and when you answer correct you get more teritory on the google map!.

But the google map is showing only to me i dont know why.

Check This:https://apps.facebook.com/sectorsase/
 Enter a number (1-4),press start, and then only the question box is showing.

My app is using Romanian Language

```
<?php
session_start();

$m = $_SESSION['m']; //3500 100%
$a = $_SESSION['answer'];


if($a==1){$lat = 44.434148;$long =26.033621;}
if($a==2){$lat =44.426057;$long =26.017585;}
if($a==3){$lat =44.439173;$long =26.015425;}
if($a==4){$lat =44.419866; $long =26.024194;}


echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>


<script>
function initialize()
{

var IPos=new google.maps.LatLng(" . $lat . "," . $long . ");
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(44.438683,26.027269),
  zoom:13,
  disableDefaultUI:true,
  draggable: false, 
  zoomControl: false, 
  scrollwheel: false, 
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:IPos,
  icon:'icn.png'

  });
 var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
  center:IPos,
  radius:" . $m .",
  strokeColor:'#0000FF',
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:2,
  fillColor:'#0000FF',
  fillOpacity:0.4
  });

  myCity.setMap(map); 
  marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<center><div id='googleMap' style='width:500px;height:380px;'></div></center>

</body>
</html>";
```

Only i can see the map from my computer but i don't understand WHY! Everyone is telling me that the map is not showing. Help!!

[image]

Comment: Where does `$lat` and `$lng` variables come from?

Comment: everything i posted is in an echo " "; so i use lat and long to set the position on the map using PHP

Comment: so does it need `. $lat .` instead of simple `$lat`

Comment: that's how i post it                    var IPos=new google.maps.LatLng(" . $lat . "," . $long . ");

Comment: so if its already in `echo` you can use `echo "this variable equals $var"` but `echo 'this variable equals $var'` wont work because you will print literal $var instead of value

Comment: i posted the full code now + a picture to show you that it is working for me the " from $lat is used to mark the string before it not to mark it as a string: ex "blablabla" . $lat . "," . $long . "continueblablabla".

Comment: and the " from the middle is used to mark the comma as a string

Comment: i realized that the map is showing only to firefox

Answer (score 0):

I would start with making sure all your CUSTOM vars and divs are namespaced so that there is no chance of them getting crossed with any existing DOM elements or objects.

Your target div, for instance, has "googleMap" as the id. I would set that to something else that wouldn't be so likely to already exist in a GOOGLE MAP as a DOM object. Try "battleTortoise" instead.